# Function not supported from hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, junit, hsqldb

I'm unit testing my DAOs using spring. I am using JPA + Hibernate.

For my tests i'm using the following hsqldb version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And here's my persistence.xml for my unit tests:

```
   <persistence-unit name="unit-test-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">   
      <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb"/>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/> 
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
      </properties>      
   </persistence-unit>
```

This is my test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration("/spring/test-context.xml")
@TestExecutionListeners({TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class})
@Transactional
public class BaseDaoTestCase extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests { 

    @Autowired
    private MockEntityDao dao;

    @Test
    public void testSave_success() {
        MockEntity e = new MockEntity();
        dao.save(e);
        assertNotNull(e.getId());
    }
}
```

Note: the idea is to test my DAOs against an in memory HSQLDB instance. Each test method runs within a transaction managed by spring.

Unfortunately, when i run this i get the following exception from hibernate:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: This function is not supported
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy23.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2764)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3275)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:757)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:732)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:736)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:854)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: This function is not supported
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.notSupported(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138)
    ... 67 more
```

The implementation of my DAO's save() method is as follows:

```
entityManager.persist(entity);
```

I'm using the following hibernate version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Does anyone have a clue on what's going on?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had similar Problem. After I update my dependencies (especially hsqldb) to:

```
    <hibernate-core-version>4.1.5.Final</hibernate-core-version>
    <spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hsqldb.version>2.2.8</hsqldb.version>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

my problem is resolved.

Comment: I had an ancient verson of HSQL in my pom. Latest version works fine

Answer (score 0):

Which mocking framework are you using? I'm just learning to work with mocks so this is just a wild guess but make sure you've done everything necessary to initialize the mock.  Maybe the problem has something to do with how the test is being setup.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the same problem working with JPA + Hibernate + HSQLDB, but not spring.
Here is my code:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction tr = em.getTransaction();
tr.begin();
em.persist(new MyEntity());
tr.commit();
em.close();
emf.close();
```

That throws me the same `This function is not supported` exception, but if I do it without the transaction, it doesn't. Like this:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.persist(new MyEntity());
em.close();
emf.close();
```

The problem now, is that I don't see the changes reflected on database.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but i have managed to resolve this issue by using the latest version of hsqldb. From what i can understand the problem was that the version of hsqldb that i used did not implement some features used by hibernate.

Comment: btw most likely you don't see your changes on the database because you haven't yet configured a transaction on your service methods. Hibernate will flush your changes once a transaction becomes committed. Unless you configure your service methods to be transactional hibernate will not send them to your database.